# Not able to insert images into database using wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, blob, file-get-contents

I am trying to run this code to take image input from front end. I know I can't simply upload images using just this  `$_POST['img']`. I read that I have to use `file_get_contents()` for this purpose. But I am new to this , I don't know How exactly to use file_get_contents()

However I tried this code, but I am unsuccessful in inserting.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label id="img">image: <input type="file" name="img" id='media'/></label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload"/>

<?php

global $wpdb;
if($_POST['Submit']) 
{
$image=$_POST['img'];

if($wpdb->insert(
    'image',
    array(

            'image' => $image


        )
) == false) echo 'Database Insertion failed';
else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
}
?>
```

This did not work. After this I tried this. But still unsuccessful.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label id="img">image: <input type="file" name="img" id='media'/></label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload"/>

<?php

global $wpdb;
if($_POST['Submit']) 
{
$image=$_POST['img'];
$item = file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
if($wpdb->insert(
    'image',
    array(

            'image' => $item


        )
) == false) echo 'Database Insertion failed';
else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
}
?>
```

for this I am getting a warning
    `Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in                  C:\xampp\htdocs\kite\wp-content\plugins\php-code-widget\execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 11`

Somebody please help me out.

And in my database, in the table "image" the column "image" has the data type BLOB, not sure if the problem is with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For file uploads you should add, `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
      ^                           ^
```

First upload to some folder and then use `file_get_contents()`

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "your path". $_FILES["file"]['name'])) {
       // image will get uploaded here
}
```

Then use

```
file_get_contents("new path")
```

Comment: Great! That helped! I am able to insert now! but, when I browse my image in the database and try to view it I see the image is damaged.  I am able to see a part of the image but not full. please suggest something for this.

Comment: image before insertion:   http://imagebin.ca/v/2N3aTdaMsMYd     screenshot of image after insertion:  http://imagebin.ca/v/2N3bIqDcRcqK

Comment: I got it! the problem is the maximum size of inserted file is 64kb hence my image ws disturbed. thanks for the help. suggest if you know how to increase the size of inserted files. I am using phpmyaddmin .

Comment: yopu are directly storing the image in db?? or only image name in db??

Comment: I am directly storing image

Comment: instead of that, store image name in db. And upload the file to that path. And access from that path.

Comment: I am a new to this, I don't know how exactly to do that. Can you suggest me any guide or a tutorial. Or if you can help me with a generic syntax it would be very helpful. thanks